# StyleGan3. The program hangs on Setting up PyTorch plugin “filtered_lrelu_plugin”

Tags: python, pytorch, stylegan

I use StyleGan3 from this repository GitHub - NVlabs/stylegan3: Official PyTorch implementation of StyleGAN3. I had everything working fine, but at some point, I interrupted the program without letting it finish. And now I’m facing the fact that the program hangs on `Setting up PyTorch plugin "filtered_lrelu_plugin"...` and nothing else happens. This happens both when trying to generate new images with gen_images.py and when trying to open the visualizer. In this case, visualizer opens but hangs with Loading and then the name of the network file. First I reinstalled torch and all related packages, then I replaced all the stylegan3 files with the ones downloaded from the repository. This didn’t help. So I completely deleted the virtual environment and re-created it by downloading and installing all the required modules. But the behavior has not changed.
Windows 10